# Finding to upper bound of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. Find an upper bound for $|a_{n+1}−a_n|$ the sequence by using given information and evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mid a_{n+1}−a_n\mid$.

1) $2≥|a_n|$

2) $|a_1−a_0|$=1

3) $1/8|a_n^2−a^2_{n-1}|≥|a_{n+1}−a_n|$

I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $|a_n^2-a_{n-1}^2|=|a_n-a_{n-1}||a_n+a_{n-1}|$.  The largest that $|a_n+a_{n-1}|$ could be is $4$, but then 
$$
\frac{1}{2}|a_n-a_{n-1}|\geq\frac{1}{8}|a_n^2-a_{n-1}^2|\geq|a_{n+1}-a_n|.
$$
Starting with $|a_0-a_1|=1$, you get that
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\geq|a_{n+1}-a_n|,
$$
so the limit is zero.

Comment: Thanks but i dont understand the numbers where to come from? (1/2 and 4).Can you explain?

Comment: $|a_n+a_{n-1}|\leq|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|\leq2+2=4$ and $4/8=1/2$.